# Is there a way to programmatically (e.g. pycaffe, etc.) given an existing caffe model .prototxt set all learning rates to zero in all layers?

Tags: conv-neural-network, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to freeze a backbone of an already existing caffe model. There has to be a way to loop through layers and set the learning rates to zero.